# ¿Cómo hacer que se refresque una ventana modal?

Tags: html5, css3

estoy creando una página que nos sirve para programar unas formaciones. La idea es tener una página con cuadros tipo calendario y que, al pulsar en "+info" abra una ventana modal con la información del curso.

He creado diferentes articles (uno por día de la semana con formación) y, a pesar de que el contenido de la ventana modal está adaptado a cada día en el código, cuando pulso el +info, siempre me muestra la información de la primera ventana modal que se creó.

Este es el código que he utilizado en la primera ventana.

```
    <article>
    <p class="mes">OCTUBRE</p>
    <p class="dia">2</p>
    <p class="texto">CURSO 1</p>
    <p class="quien">con xxxxxxx
        en xxxxxxxx.<a href="#" target="_blank"><img class="icon" src="images/iraweb.gif"></a></p>
 
  <!-- aquí ese invoca la ventana modal -->

 <a class="masfechas" href="#openModal">Ver todas las fechas del curso</a>
    <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
        <div class="ventanamodal">
            <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
            <h2>Fechas de la formación "xxxxxxx"</h2>
            <h3>Con xxxxxxx. Impartido en xxxxxxxx.</h3>
            <p>2 de octubre</p><p>13 de noviembre</p><p>18 de diciembre</p><p>15 de enero</p><p>12 de febrero</p><p>12 de marzo</p><p>9 de abril</p>
        </div>
    </div>    
    </article>
```

¿Me podéis orientar un poco para "forzar" que se refresque la nueva información en cada ventana modal que llamo desde el resto de articles para que muestre el correcto?
Si estoy equivocado con el tipo de funcionalidad para implementar, por favor, indicadme ya que soy un poco nuevo con esto y solo necesito una ventana emergente (que no sea tipo pop up) que muestre la información oportuna.

Comment: Buenas tardes. La pregunta está bien, y se entiende tu propósito pero, se necesita más información de tu código, cómo llamas a la función, y un ejemplo de tu base de datos. O sea, falta mostrar tu código JavaScript o jquery, con la que estás trabajando, para ayudarte

Comment: Buenas, la verdad es que no hay ninguna BBDD, ni código Javascript, tan solo es el HTML que os he puesto y luego ya el CSS3 que le da el aspecto a la ventana :/

Comment: Tu problema requiere JavaScript para solucionar

Comment: Un modal normal funciona con JavaScript o jquery

Comment: Intentare buscar otra opción entonces. La plantilla que encontré solo erar para html5 + css3 y la verdad es que me la abrió perfecta....

Gracias